# How to get submit button on same line as email form

Tags: forms, email, input

I have a WordPress site I'm working on and no matter where I put my email signup form, I can't seem to get the button to be on the same line as the box where you enter your email. Is there something wrong with my code that I'm overlooking?

```
<div id="robly_embed_signup">
  <form action="https://list.robly.com/subscribe/post" method="post" id="robly_embedded_subscribe_form" name="robly_embedded_subscribe_form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="821e061e2be0076acb86297c73307f0f" />
                <div class="robly_field_group"><input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="DATA0" class="required" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" value="enter your email address" onfocus="if (this.value=='enter your email address') this.value='';"><input type="submit" name="subscribe" id="robly_embedded_subscribe" class="button" value="Subscribe" />
```

This is my website: http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the width of the email input field. I got it down to 84% before the subscribe button went in line with it.

You also have the ID of the email input field as DATA0 which appears twice since you have it in the header and in the green area above the content, and IDs should appear only once per document. I suggest giving them unique IDs* then assigning a class like "emailField" and adding CSS to your stylesheet like this:

```
.emailField{
   width:84%;
}
```

*Since you also have some javascript that references the DATA0 ID, you'll need to update it as well if you change the IDs.